# Trigger Checkbox Click Event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using

```
    Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 101").Value = 1
```

in a called sub during a `Sub Worksheet_Change` event, but it only sets the checkbox value to 1, it doesn't actually trigger the checkbox as a mouse click does - which normally runs code associated with this checkbox in the `Sub CheckBox101_Click()` event.

How would I code this so that the called sub, sets the value to 1, but also "triggers" the checkbox to run the code within `Sub CheckBox101_Click()` ?

Comment: You can just add the call to `CheckBox101_Click` to the code that sets it to 1.

Comment: Sure that works. I think it didn't before because I was running a different code in the `CheckBox101_Click1` sub. Works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the call to `CheckBox101_Click` to the code that sets it to 1

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 101").Value = 1
CheckBox101_Click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a `CheckBox101_Click()` event handler. Instead create a `CheckBox101_Change()` handler.

Then when you call `Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 101").Value = 1` the event fires without you needing to explicitly call it.

And it still works when a user clicks the check box and changes the value.